# Centered masonry content inside of gridster

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-masonry, gridster

I need to put a dynamic tile layout inside a gridster widget. I have put there masonry grid but I want the content to be centred instead of floated left.
I have found that I need to change **isFitWidth** property to true and a fixed sized **columnWidth** but since the gridster widget can be resized it doesn't work very well. I tried to initialize masonry with these properties dynamically inside gridster resize property but it doesn't work either.

Any ideas how to make it work?
Or should i use a different grid instead of masonry

HTML:

```
<div class="gridster">
  <ul class="ul-grid">
    <li>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="grid">
          <div class="grid-item">
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.grid {
  background: #DDD;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #0D8;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.7);
  margin: 3%;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item'
  });
});
```

[image](http://pl.tinypic.com/r/2e52i54/8)

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Cepheix/pkqraL81/)